Help me identify this old, lugged, red, Schwinn road bike with stem shifters and centerpull brakes
Here is the bike:

I couldn't find a serial number anywhere on it, so suggestions for finding that are welcome as well. Reverse Google image search suggests a Le Tour 1977, which I am doubting because here the fork lug is painted red, while the Le Tour is chrome. The other image search suggestion was a World Sport, but in that case the fork was completely red, as opposed to the silver details by the dropouts.
Any help is appreciated!

It's a loverly 70s or 80s steel road bike.  What do you hope to do with the info of an exact model/year match?

The components look mostly correct for a Le Tour. Why wouldn't it be the Le Tour II in your link? Decals can rub or be peeled off.

The Le Tour IV example is already losing the decals, you can see.

@Criggie my reason for asking is 10% so I can put an accurate listing up when I resell, 90% my own curiosity because I've had a hard time identifying.

@Noise my reasoning is because the fork lugs (is that what they're called?) are chrome-plated in the stock image, but red on mine. Is it possible that they put the chrome finish over the red paint on the lugs?

Lucas, The chrome has to be applied first, to the bare steel. My own bike (Cinelli) has the fork fully chromed, even though it is 90percent painted. The masking takes time and is more fiddly at the crown than the lower leg so eliminating the chrome crown (even if there is chrome under the paint) is a way to economise.

The fork can also be replaced due to accident or warranty and the manufacturer may not supply something completely identical. This is true in many industries including auto and cycling.

At bikehistory.org there is a nice section on the history of the Schwinn Le Tour line.
Focusing on chrome fork tips, crank type, and the Schwinn decal location it looks like the bike in the question is a 1977 LeTour II with a 21" frame in scarlet.
Here is the 1976 model

The down tube decal is different from the bike in the question.
Here is the 1977 model

The Le Tour decal has moved to the top tube. The model is now the Le Tour II.
The 1977 came in "Scarlet, Violet, Pearlescent Orange" and had a "Schwinn-Approved aluminum alloy" crank
The 1979 model had a painted fork crown. It might be a 1977 with a 1979 replacement fork. Check for branding on the crank. It looks like the Schwinn Approved crank in the picture. If it turns out to be a Sugino then it's a 1979.
In 1978 the name changed to LeTour III and came in "Pearl Orange, Pearl blue". No scarlet so it' can't be a 1978 LeTour III. It still had a "Schwinn-Approved aluminum alloy" crank
In 1979 the crank changed to the Sugino Super Maxi alloy and it is now called the Le Tour IV

In 1980 the LeTour had a Sugino Super Maxi alloy crank.
The picture for the bike spans two pages.
The back of the bike is here
The front of the bike is here
Schwinn never went back to a Schwinn-Apporved aluminum alloy crank
The Traveler from 1977 had chrome for tips and the Schwinn decal on the down tube but it had a steel cotterless crank rather than aluminum.
The World Sport came out in 1979 and did not have chrome fork tips
Here is a collection of reasonably good page scans for catalogs from 1971 to 1980

It does indeed have a Schwinn-approved crank, so I guess it's a '77 Le Tour II. Thanks so much for the detective work!

Maybe a Traveler. I have one of the same timeframe. 

If you have one, could you please add a picture of it to your answer? That would make it much more valuable and defendable.

Loverly bike !  I see its been converted to singlespeed/fixed gear with a cog on each side.  The crankset looks original but someone has removed the extra chainrings.   The white paint on the head tube-is that original or later?   I see the handlebars have been changed, but what I don't get is the stem appears to be a threadless style while the bike still has its original threadded fork.  Is there a threadded-to-threadless adapter in the fork's steerer tube or is it just clamped around the existing 1" steerer tube?
